# when `each` finished, start another `each`

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to do the next thing: when first part finished (including the function `AccountClicked` that gets details from the server), start the second part.

how can I do it please?

```
    // first part
    $('#accountsTable li input').each(function () {
        isGetLastSearchOperation = true;
        var accountId = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($.inArray(accountId, LastSearchedAccountsIds) > -1) {
            AreClickedButtonsEnable = true;
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
            AccountClicked(this);
        }
        // uncheck the other goals
        else {
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
        }
    });

    // second part
    $('#commercialGoalsTable li input').each(function () {
        isGetLastSearchOperation = true;
        var goalId = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($.inArray(goalId, LastSearchedGoalsIds) > -1) {
            AreClickedButtonsEnable = true;
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
            //CommercialGoalClicked(this);
        }
        // uncheck the other goals
        else {
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
        }
    });
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: Javascript is single threaded, and there is no aysn requests. so that is what it does.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to say...  When it finishes executing a line, doesn't it move on to the next line, like almost every other programming language?

Comment: @bingjie2680 you are wrong, the 2nd loop will start before each function returns

Comment: @Hogan `.each()` by itself is not async.

Comment: @Hogan, are you sure, make a test to see the result.

Comment: I don't need to make a test... here is an example question that uses promise to solve this promblem -- I believe this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006732/jquery-promise-in-function-with-each

Comment: @JanDvorak - each does not wait for the function to return.

Comment: this is the test: http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/75WPh/, see the console.log

Comment: Another test: http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/cAVTr/

Comment: @bingjie2680 - that fiddle does not have an asnyc function in the first each.  I'll make you an example.

Comment: @Hogan That's the point. `.each()` is not async. Functions called in the `.each()` callback could be async, but `.each()` is not async.

Comment: I know. but neither does the question from what we can see. unless the AccountClicked is an async request.

Comment: @hogan it does. It doesn't wait for any contained asynchronous operations, but I can't see any.

Comment: He edited the question to add _"including the function AccountClicked that gets details from the server"_. I assume that's the async part.

Comment: Yea, AccountClicked could be asynch!

Comment: you are right; @JasonP, the question must be updated when we were discussing. :)

Comment: I didn't set async true or false.. so it's true..

Comment: maybe I will do it with for loop instead of `each`?

Comment: @AlonShmiel for loop instead wouldn't help.

Comment: Here is the example fiddle... but I see it is a moot point.  It was clear to me from the start he had internal async to have to problem -- But I guess I assume the best. http://jsfiddle.net/bingjie2680/75WPh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution would probably be to change up your code so you can send one ajax request.

Since `AccountClicked()` uses ajax and is async, I would first change that function to return a `promise` object, then do wait until all of the promises have been resolved like so:

```
var promises = [];

// first part
$('#accountsTable li input').each(function () {
    isGetLastSearchOperation = true;
    var accountId = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($.inArray(accountId, LastSearchedAccountsIds) > -1) {
        AreClickedButtonsEnable = true;
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
        promises.push(AccountClicked(this));
    }
    // uncheck the other goals
    else {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    }
});

$.when.apply(null, promises).done(function () {

    // second part
    $('#commercialGoalsTable li input').each(function () {
        isGetLastSearchOperation = true;
        var goalId = $(this).attr('id');
        if ($.inArray(goalId, LastSearchedGoalsIds) > -1) {
            AreClickedButtonsEnable = true;
            $(this).attr('checked', true);
            //CommercialGoalClicked(this);
        }
        // uncheck the other goals
        else {
            $(this).attr('checked', false);
        }
    });

});
```

A couple of simple options for returning a promise from a function:

```
function AccountClicked() {
    return $.ajax({
        // ...
    });
}

function AccountClicked() {
    var def = $.Deferred();

    $.ajax({
        // ...
    }).done(function() {
        def.resolve();
    });

    return def.promise();
}
```

Comment: thank you but it doesn't work.. it entered the second part before the `accountclicked` calls finished..

Comment: Did you change `AccountClicked` to return a promise, and resolve the promise when the ajax function has completed?

Comment: _"yes, I copied what you wrote.."_ - That seems to be a self-contradicting statement. My answer doesn't contain the code for the `AccountClicked()` function that you need to change.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand you.. how can I return a promise? `return promise;`?

Comment: I updated my answer with a couple of simplified examples of returning a promise.

Comment: This is a great answer and clear about how to add in a promise (with the examples) I took out the close vote because this is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You could just add an `if` statement at the end of your first each loop that find the number of elements, when it reaches that high number, start the next each loop.

```
// first part
var numElem = $('#accountsTable li input').length;
$('#accountsTable li input').each(function (e) {//Notice the 'e' in this function for your index number
    isGetLastSearchOperation = true;
    var accountId = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($.inArray(accountId, LastSearchedAccountsIds) > -1) {
        AreClickedButtonsEnable = true;
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
        AccountClicked(this);
    }
    // uncheck the other goals
    else {
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    }
    if(e>=numElem-1){
            // second part
        $('#commercialGoalsTable li input').each(function () {
            isGetLastSearchOperation = true;
            var goalId = $(this).attr('id');
            if ($.inArray(goalId, LastSearchedGoalsIds) > -1) {
                AreClickedButtonsEnable = true;
                $(this).attr('checked', true);
                //CommercialGoalClicked(this);
            }
            // uncheck the other goals
            else {
                $(this).attr('checked', false);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

EDIT ::  Forgot zero position, edited the if statement to take care of that.

Here's a fiddle of an example http://jsfiddle.net/L4asQ/

Comment: Isn't this different... you have the 2nd loop in the first loop.

Comment: this does exactly as he asks, Do the first part, then when it finishes, do the second part.